# Uninstall Work account and wipe all associated apps

Tags: uninstallation, accounts

I recently tried ManageEnigne Mobile Device Mangement plus for my phone. It was working fine. It created a work account and installed secondary Chrome, Play Store with a work icon.

Now I have finished testing the app and want to uninstall it. I followed the [instructions here.](https://www.manageengine.com/mobile-device-management/how-to/mdm-uninstall-android-agent.html)The app was successfully uninstalled but the work apps created like the chrome and play store are all present in my device.

I tried [the steps mentioned here.](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en)In my Redmi Note 4 there is no work option in the accounts section. There are however two Google accounts now. Since I used the same email id to sign in I don't know which is which and I don't want to uninstall my personal account at any cost.

Can anyone help me wipe the work account from my phone?

Note : I launched a remote wipe of Corporate data from the web console and did not delete anything.